# Access and print nth element of sub array, for every array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a multidimensional array:

```
@multarray =  ( [ "one", "two", "three" ],
                [  4,   5,  6,  ],
                [ "alpha", "beta", "gamma" ]
              );
```

I can access `@multarray[0]`

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] "one"
        [1] "two"
        [2] "three"
    ]
]
```

or even `@multarray[0][0]`

```
"one"
```

But, how do I access say the 1st sub element of every sub array? Something akin to `multarray[*][0]` to produce:

```
"one"
4
"alpha"
```

Comment: Just an FYI: `@multiarray[0]` is a single element array slice.  `$multiarray[0]` is accessing the scalar at offset zero in an array.  Prefer the latter syntax unless you really intend to use a slice.  Remember that in Perl the *sigil* follows the type of value we're working with. Thus, `$` is for a single scalar, even if it is a component of an aggregate data type such as a hash or an array.

Comment: Related to DavidO's comment, make sure you always `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';`. With warnings enabled, `@multarray[0]` will give the warning "Scalar value @multarray[0] better written as $multarray[0]"

Comment: I recommend that you prefer `Data::Dump` or `Data::Dumper` over `Data::Printer` when formatting data for presentation in a question. The last can be useful for personal use at a command prompt, but it adds additional information that can be confusing out of context, especially to someone unfamiliar with the module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and dereference each array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @multarray =  ( 
    [ "one", "two", "three" ],
    [  4,   5,  6,  ],
    [ "alpha", "beta", "gamma" ]
);

my @subs = map { $_->[0] } @multarray;
print Dumper(\@subs);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'one',
          4,
          'alpha'
        ];
```

See also: [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 3):

Using a `for()` loop, you can loop over the outer array, and use any of the inner elements. In this example, I've set `$elem_num` to `0`, which is the first element. For each loop over the outer array, we take each element (which is an array reference), then, using the `$elem_num` variable, we print out the contents of the inner array's first element:

```
my $elem_num = 0;

for my $elem (@multarray){
    print "$elem->[$elem_num]\n";
}
```